# Is there a way of code folding the properties just like functions in Xcode?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, code-folding

I like to work with code folding by using `option + command + right or left` key bindings. It is appearing to me more readable at first glance, especially for long classes.

Let me explain with an example, suppose we have a class:

```
func someFunction(input: String) -> Bool {
    // if you click command option left arrow , case 1 
    ...
}
```

---

```
func someFunction(input: String) -> Bool {} // it is being like this, case 2. Perfect.
```

---

```
//MARK - Properties
var x: String = "a"
var y: Int = 3
var z: Double = 3.0 // the property list could be longer,
```

---

`properties:` i want to see something like this, at least at one line but but could not find a way

This is okay for methods or class as they have `{}`, but what about properties? Is there a way of folding them in the same way or a tricky way? (But I don't want to affect my code performance as well.)

Comment: I think the term you're looking for is "code folding" instead of "squeezing/extending". And no, I don't think there's currently a way to fold just the properties.

Comment: @Tyler thanks i edited my question, looks like no way but maybe someone has idea or a good suggestion :)

Comment: This would be nice, though if you have so many properties, it's a good indication your object is too big :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid the best you can do is to move the properties off into another type (i.e. a struct). You can keep that struct definition in another file or, if it is in this file, you can fold *that*:

[image]

Imagine there are 100 properties; they would all be inside the Props struct and could be declared in another file or, as in the screen shot, hidden by folding.

Making a sequence of properties foldable sounds like a reasonable enhancement request but I doubt it would actually happen; I've never seen an IDE that does this (though I don't get out much so who knows, maybe such a thing exists).

Answer (score 1):

As of Xcode 12 there is no way to do this. `Editor > Fold Methods & Functions` (`⇧ ⌥ ⌘ ←`) will not fold properties.

The best you can do is put the cursor on each unfolded property and choose `Editor > Code Folding > Fold` (`⌥ ⌘ ←`).

I guess Apple is trying to strongly suggest that developers use properties sparingly? It's ridiculous that this isn't an option.

Comment: XCode 13 hasn`t as well :/